# Ошибка в on Resume при подключении DisplayHomeAsUpEnabled?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

```
public class sovety_Fragment extends Fragment {



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sovety, null);





        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  // подчеркивает красным getSupprotActionbar
    }

}
```

Текст ошибки:

```
cannot resolve method getSupportActionBar()
```

Comment: Наведите мышь на подчёркнутое место и расскажите что именно за ошибка.

Comment: cannot resolve method getSupportActionBar()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28977583/3212712) надо просто скастовать результат вызова `getActivity()` к `ActionBarActivity`:

```
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()
//или к AppCompatActivity если вы не хотите пользоваться устаревшим ActionBarActivity
```

---

Кстати, этот ответ гугл выдаёт первой строкой при запросе:

> [getActivity().getSupportActionBar() cant resolve method](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=getActivity().getSupportActionBar()%20cant%20resolve%20method)

Comment: А как зделать что бы стрелочка после перехода из в фрагмента назад в активити пропадала?

Comment: @Андрей, вы пробовали `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)`?

Comment: Добавил код ,непомогает(( getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

Comment: @Андрей, а если так: `setHomeButtonEnabled(false);`?

Comment: @Андрей, вот тут ещё посмотрите: [тык](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33792765/3212712)

Comment: ничего не помогло((( после переход в фрагмент при нажатии на назад стрелочка остается((

Comment: @Андрей, создайте тогда отдельный вопрос с подробным описанием проблемы, но без лишнего кода.